# How to store an Array in a table MySQL (For NodeJS)

Tags: mysql, node.js

I've recently started learning MySQL and I've been trying to apply it with Node to make a REST API instead of using the usual Mongo Node stack.

However, one problem I've run into is storing arrays and objects in MySQL. In Mongo it's super easy, and in MySQL, it seems it isn't as easy.

Basically I want to return a JSON with a structure like this;

```js
{
  "name": "My Product",
  "desc": "Product description",
  "images": [
    {
      "caption": "Product Photo 1",
      "url": "http://"
    },
    {
      "caption": "Product Photo 2",
      "url": "http://"
    },
    {
      "caption": "Product Photo 3",
      "url": "http://"
    },
  ],
  
  "pricing": {
    "standard": {
      "title": "The Standard Product",
      "desc": "Standard Product Description",
      "prices": {
        "usd": 10.99,
        "eur": 9.99,
        "gbp": 8.99
      }
    },
    "deluxe": {
      "title": "The Deluxe Product",
      "desc": "Deluxe Product Description",
      "prices": {
        "usd": 19.99,
        "eur": 17.99,
        "gbp": 15.99
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, I'm having some troubles understanding the concepts of achieving storage for properties like the images array.

I have read that the best practice is to store them in another table so that you can query them and such. But I'm not sure I understand this since if I'm adding a new table for every array/object I will end up with tons of them on larger scale projects?

I have also read about storing it as a JSON string but that doesn't really accomplish what I'm after, so I'm more so looking into the above solution.

Comment: You wouldn't create a new table for each array, but one for each kind of array.  What difference is there between an array and a table?  All prices for all pricings for all products would go in one table.  A very complex application may need a hundred tables, it depends on the quality of the design.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using MySQL 8.0? It supports a [document store](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/document-store.html) offering similar to MongoDB as well available via the X DevAPI, so you don't need to use the "low-level" `JSON` datatype if you don't want to, and still achieve the same.

Since it seems like you are using Node.js, there's also an [X DevAPI](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mysql/xdevapi) client implementation you can use for that purpose.

Disclaimer: I'm the lead dev working in that X DevAPI implementation.

Comment: Well, I'm not necessarily looking for a document store (hence why I'm trying mysql instead of mongo). I like how MySQL is structured and fixed, I just hate how hard it is to define an object or array.

Since I posted this question, I've been looking and still can't seem to find even a semi-decent tutorial or guide on how to map arrays/objects to another table and reference it. It's pretty frustrating.

Comment: You mentioned it was easy on MongoDB, that's what triggered my answer. But why is it hard on MySQL? Why can't you just store the structure as is using a `JSON` datatype then? Is your problem querying the table later? Now I'm a bit confused by your question but, from what I can tell, it seems like a schema design issue, which in this case is mostly SQL approach vs NoSQL approach. If that's the case, that should be pretty much determined by your application's data access patterns.

Answer (score 0):

https://scotch.io/tutorials/working-with-json-in-mysql
Read this article

create datatype column as JSON
and you can Dump this data

```
{
  "name": "My Product",
  "desc": "Product description",
  "images": [
    {
      "caption": "Product Photo 1",
      "url": "http://"
    },
    {
      "caption": "Product Photo 2",
      "url": "http://"
    },
    {
      "caption": "Product Photo 3",
      "url": "http://"
    },
  ],

  "pricing": {
    "standard": {
      "title": "The Standard Product",
      "desc": "Standard Product Description",
      "prices": {
        "usd": 10.99,
        "eur": 9.99,
        "gbp": 8.99
      }
    },
    "deluxe": {
      "title": "The Deluxe Product",
      "desc": "Deluxe Product Description",
      "prices": {
        "usd": 19.99,
        "eur": 17.99,
        "gbp": 15.99
      }
    }
  }
}
```

later you can query on this data
here ref mysql doc https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html